# Is smooth deformation an extrinsic property of surfaces?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, geometric-topology, knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology

The extrinsic properties of surfaces are those properties dependent on the embedding of their ambient space and otherwise intrinsic. Loosely speaking, in Weeks' *The shape of space* he mentioned that two surfaces have the same intrinsic topology/geometry if the Flatlander (2-dimensional creatures) can't tell them from each other while they have the same extrinsic topology/geometry if the Spacelander (3-dimensional creatures) can't tell them from each other.

For example, Gaussian curvature is an intrinsic property but normal curvature is an extrinsic property e.g. a bent square and a flat square. Homeomorphism is an intrinsic property and it's well known that trefoil and circle have the same intrinsic topology i.e. they're homeomorphic. Even more, the embedding maps are isotopic which implies isotopy type is an intrinsic property. Therefore, we have two tools to tell knots from each other: ambient isotopy and smooth isotopy. Clearly, the ambient isotopy type is an extrinsic property since it's the homotopy of embeddings of the ambient space.

Now my question comes: is smooth deformation (i.e. smooth isotopy) an extrinsic property of surfaces? I guess yes since it distinguishes knots, but I'm confused why deformation is independent of its embedding while smooth deformation does?

Comment: The fact that all knots are isotopic to an unknot in $\mathbb R^3$ comes from the fact that you can pull a knot tight, until the knotted part disappears. This is a continuous but not differentiable operation. However it fails for links of more than one component. So in your sense, even isotopy class is not intrinsic for general 1-manifolds.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip I haven't learned links yet, but that makes sense to me. So do you mean that isotopy class is not intrinsic for 1-manifolds  but is intrinsic for 2-manifolds?

Comment: No, it is not intrinisic for 2-manifolds either. Imagine a knotted torus. This is not isotopic to an unknotted one because you can't pull the knot tight like in the case of a knotted circle.

Comment: Whatever extrinsic means, I would say that for any two topological spaces $A,X$, isotopy classes of embeddings of $A$ in $X$ are extrinsic: it is an equivalence relation on that class of embeddings, which makes it extrinsic. Now it's possible that in a certain situation there's only one such equivalence class, but that does not make the relation intrinsic.

Comment: Having said that, this "extrinsic/intrinsic" dichotomy is really just for your intuition. If you understand the concept of isotopy classes and how its behavior differs (depending on continuous/smooth, or depending on 1-dimensional, 2-dimensional) then you're doing well.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks so much for the clarification and that makes sense!

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip, thanks for the clear example!